# Customer Google Analytics in Web App

Tags: web-applications, google-analytics

I have a web app where people can create custom content on the web which is hosted by my service. I want to provide users with the ability to track activity on their specific page via Google Analytic. I've seen some other companies providing this option (MailChimp).

I was wondering if anyone had experience in implementing this kind of solution and might be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app just needs to emit the Google analytics code and their account id when their page is rendered.  Maybe you can allow you users to enter the tracking Id in their account settings, then you can output the JavaScript tracking code provided by google analytics with the logged in user's analytics id.

Comment: Okay I thought it might work that way but wasn't sure. Thanks for the help.